# How to implement world-coordinate-aligned repeated texture mapping in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

When you create a brush in a 3D map editor such as Valve's Hammer Editor, textures of the object are by default repeated and aligned to the world coordinates.

**How can i implement this functionality using OpenGL?**

**Can glTexGen be used to achieve this?**

**Or do i have to use texture matrix somehow?**

If i create 3x3 box, then it's easy:
Set GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T to GL_REPEAT
Set texturecoords to 3,3 at the edges.

But if the object is not an axis aligned convexhull it gets, uh, a bit complicated.

Basically i want to create functionality of face edit sheet from Valve Hammer:

[image: Valve Hammer Face Edit tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can use texture coordinate generation for this. But I recommend using a vertex shader that generates the texture coordinates from the transformed vertex coordinates. Be a bit more specific (I don't know Hammer very well).

---

After seeing the video I understand your confusion. I think you should know, that Hammer/Source probably don't have the drawing API generate texture coordinates, but produce them internally.

So what you can see there are textures that are projected on either the X, Y or Z plane, depending in which major direction the face is pointing to. It then uses the local vertex coordinates as texture coordinates.

You can implement this in the code loading a model to a Vertex Buffer Object (more efficient, since the computation is done only once), or in a GLSL vertex shader. I'll give you the pseudocode:

```
cross(v1, v2):
    return { x = v1.y * v2.z - v1.z * v2.y,
             y = v2.x * v1.z - v2.z * v1.x, // <- "swapped" order!
             z = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x }

normal(face): 
    return cross(face.position[1] - face.position[0], face.position[2] - face.position[0])

foreach face in geometry:
    n = normal(face) // you'd normally precompute the normals and store them
    if abs(n.x) > max(abs(n.y), abs(n.z)): // X major axis, project to YZ plane
        foreach (i, pos) in enumerate(face.position):
             face.texcoord[i] = { s = pos.y, t = pos.z }

    if abs(n.y) > max(abs(n.x), abs(n.z)): // Y major axis, project to XZ plane
        foreach (i, pos) in enumerate(face.position):
             face.texcoord[i] = { s = pos.x, t = pos.z }

    if abs(n.z) > max(abs(n.y), abs(n.x)): // Z major axis, project to XY plane
        foreach (i, pos) in enumerate(face.position):
             face.texcoord[i] = { s = pos.x, t = pos.y }
```

To make this work with glTexGen texture coordinate generation, you'd have to split your models into parts of each major axis. What glTexGen does is just the mapping step `face.texcoord[i] = { s = pos.<>, t = pos.<> }`. In a vertex shader you can do the branching directly.

Comment: The question is: how to implement world-coordinate-aligned repeated texture mapping in openGL? Valve Hammer is just an example (see: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8R4aWvRQP-E)

Comment: This could work, I'll try this. I tried finding orthogonal basis vectors for plane of the face and then projecting face vertices on them. s = Vector.Dot(basis1, vertex); t = Vector.Dot(basis2, vertex); The problem in this approach is that the plane can have several orthogonal basis vectors rotated around plane normal. And i'm not sure how to get plane basis vectors what are somehow aligned with the origin.